# WPF ViewBox Zoom

Tags: c#, wpf, zooming, viewbox

Is there a way to zoom a viewbox content, excpet for one control?
I have a viewbox with a grid, and in this grid I have some controls and I'm trying to zoom all the controls in the viewbox except one, is it possible?

Many thanks,
Paulo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a grid to add layers to your layout.  That way, you can zoom one set of items, and leave another set un-zoomed.

```
<Grid>
  <Viewbox>
    <!-- Controls to zoom -->
  </Viewbox>
  <!-- Control to exclude from zoom -->
</Grid>
```

The order of the view box and the other controls in XAML will depend upon which layer appears on top.

If that doesn't quite do what you want, leave a comment and I'll revisit the answer.

**EDIT** You want the unzoomed control to be positioned relative to the (0,0) of the `Viewbox`.  That will happen in this situation because both children of the grid are in cell (0,0) which means that their top-left corners are aligned.  Can you give an example of what you have in XAML, and what's wrong with it (perhaps edit your original question)?

Here's some XAML to try:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  Background="Green">
  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Viewbox>
      <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="10" Height="10" />
    </Viewbox>
    <TextBlock>I am positioned at (0,0)</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Margin="50,50">I am positioned at (50,50)</TextBlock>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

That gives a layout like this:

http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/2045/layout1m.png

But note that when the height is reduced, the grid becomes wider than the view box, and so the content is layed out like this:

http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/9397/layout2i.png

I guess that's not what you want.  In that case, you use a canvas and go for something like this:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  Background="Green">
  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Viewbox>
      <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="10" Height="10" />
    </Viewbox>
    <Canvas>
      <TextBlock>I am positioned at (0,0)</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Margin="50,50">I am positioned at (50,50)</TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Which looks like this:

http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/6743/layout3i.png